Kosher alcohol etc
I have been using the CRC's kosher liquor list for many years.
It seems that just in the past 2 years or so, they have dropped a lot of the brands.
Can someone discuss if there was some sort of major change in the alcohol industry that led to the CRC not certifying a huge amount of alcohol brands any more?
For example, Jack Daniels was okay 5 years ago but it is on the no-no list now.

Did you try asking them?

Just FYI, often when the factory changes, the kosher status changes, pending new instructions about the new factory.
